# TypeScript compiler error TS1127

Tags: typescript

**TypeScript Version:**

1.8.10

Hi.

I still have the error code TS1127 when I try to compile a file.
I use the code from the quick tutorial.

**Code :**

```
 function greeter(person: string){
      return "Hello, " + person;
    }
    var user = [0, 1, 2];
    document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

**Expected behavior:**

```
_greeter.ts(7,26):_Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target_
```

**Actual behavior:**

```
greeter.ts(1,1): error TS1127: Invalid character.
greeter.ts(1,2): error TS1127: Invalid character.
greeter.ts(1,3): error TS1127: Invalid character.
greeter.ts(1,4): error TS1127: Invalid character.
```

Comment: You passing through an array, however, your function expects a string.

Comment: yes but the compiler must return 'parameters do not match any signature of call target' and not error TS1127

Comment: The error is stating there are invalid characters in `greeter.ts` on line 1, columns 1-4. Verify there are not any hidden Unicode characters in the .ts file. Or better yet, just create a new greeter.ts file from scratch and type everything by hand; I suspect the invalid characters are due to a copy/paste.

Comment: Thank you. you are right copy/past just added a hidden invalid character. I have no error now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> (1,1): error TS1127: Invalid character.

The file contains an invalid unicode character at position `1,1`

## QuickFix

Create a new file and make sure it just contains the right characters

## Better fix

Use a hex editor to figure out what went south.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The issue happened because of copy/past since hidden invalid character was added. I rewrote the code manually from scratch everything work well now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on VS code editor then you can press **CTRL+Shift+P** and then search "reload". If you run this then your issue should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing CTRL+Shift+P then select refresh window. After that check your NVM version using command 'nvm list' select the required version which matches with your project then delete old 'node_modules'. After doing all ng build.